# Why to make abstract if we have overriding concepts?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Why we should go for abstract class, if we have the concept of overriding. Anyways we have to extend abstract class to give the definition of abstract method, we can simply extend and override its abstract method, then what is the logic in making it abstract ?

Comment: It's the bastard child of Class and Interface, not quite having its' exclusive purpose, yet being able to accommodate the needs of both class and interface. Good answers on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/96947/why-should-i-declare-a-class-as-an-abstract-class)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you will build a lot of different type of cars: family cars, sport cars, F1 cars ...

For all of these, the accelerate() method will have a very different implementation. 
Let's say you would not make Car an abstract class, and provide the implementation of accelerate.

If someone were to build an F1 car, he might think: we already have the functionality of accelerate, no reason not to use it. In the end, we could end up with all types of cars accelerating the exact same way.

That would lead to either very slow F1 races, or basic traffic even the Flash wouldn't want to be a pedestrian in.

The abstract class is to tell 'what' to do, not 'how' it should be done, but also has the possibility to add some non-abstract methods, unlike interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract methods cannot have an implementation, so it is not the case that you would be providing an implementation in an abstract class only to override it in a (concrete) subclass.

The purpose of an abstract method is to define a common *behavior* which *all* subclasses will possess.  However, this behavior is unknown at the level of the abstract class.  To give a trivial example:

```
abstract public class Animal {
    public abstract void eat();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("I eat dog biscuits");
    }
}
```

Here, all `Animal`s eat, but we do not know what they eat at the outset, until we have created a particular subclass.  An abstract method is well suited for this problem.

Comment: what a coincidence...

Answer (score 1):

class Animal:

```
public abstract class Animal{
    protected abstract void makeNoise();
}
```

Dog:

```
class Dog extends Animal{
    protected void makeNoise(){
        print("woof");
    }
}
```

Cat:

```
class Cat extends Animal{
    protected void makeNoise(){
        print("meow");
    }
}
```

when I want some noise:

```
private Animal animal;  // could be a (cute) dog or a cat or something else.
public void makeNoise(){
    this.animal.makeNoise();
}
```

In a word, abstract class gives definitions, as you have said. And definition could be important especially when I want to implement specific logic without knowing details.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you don't want to allow an instance of your class, you need to make it abstract class.

Also, abstract class can content some methods which is common logic for all it sub-classes.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class cannot be instantiated. By making a class abstract you make it clear for its users that it is designed only for extension.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an abstract class Shape2D. You know, that you can draw something like that, but exactly, HOW? You can't define method draw() for Shape2D. This method is only a concept, that objects that are Shape2D, can be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for making it abstract is so you won't create instances from this specific class as it is incomplete without the extended behavior (implemented by its sub classes).

It provides a common behavior for its sub-classes so you won't have to write this common behavior for each sub-class

Answer (score 0):

You create abstract class to make sure no one will instaniate it. Abstract class may have the main logic, but still needs some more info that should be provided by abstract methods.